# Error while checking if an array contains an object

Tags: javascript

I am having this problem, I am trying to check if an object is inside an array but it is telling me that it is false, when in fact it should be true.

```
const checkfileExist = (docType, obj) => {
    if (docType === "COC") {
      let cocArray = JSON.parse(dbData[0].COC);
      console.log("COC DATA", cocArray);
      console.log("OBJ DATA", obj);
      console.log(cocArray.includes(obj));
    }
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEFda.png)

Comment: Check the image for the logs.

Comment: For objects, ```includes``` check for instance of object not the value of object.

Comment: Thank you @AmitKumar, that was the problem i wasn't aware of that, leson learned.

Answer (score 1):

`cocArray` is an array of objects that parsed from a string, although the object it contains looks exactly the same as `obj`, but they are completely different references. Thus `cocArray.includes(obj)` will aways return `false`.

You need to manually detect whether an object has the same key value pairs as another, such as:

```js
const checkfileExist = (docType, obj) => {
    if (docType === "COC") {
        let cocArray = JSON.parse(dbData[0].COC);
        console.log("COC DATA", cocArray);
        console.log("OBJ DATA", obj);

        const isExist = cocArray.some(item => Object.entries(obj).every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value));
        console.log(isExist);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `if` block, try inserting

```
obj.cow = 'moo':
console.log({cocArray, obj});
```

My guess is that property `moo` will appear as added to `obj` but not `cocArray[0]` because despite having the same values they are actually different objects.